# Sharpness of the maximum of the weight

Tags: statistical-mechanics, terminology

What does the sharpness of maximum mean? In Statistical mechanics, when we find the most probable configuration, then we also have to define its sharpness. What is this sharpness?

Comment: It just means how wide the spread, the uncertainty in where this sharp peak is.